# TinyBox how get passing value from parent pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

Recently I have faced a problem which do not know how to pass value from parent page to a tinybox. The following is my source code; is there any idea can help me to achieve this? A edit.php wrap inside a tinybox so when I click on a specific column suppose the value should pass to the edit.php (tinybox) and also the value will display on the textfield, but it just simply doesn't work. I am new in PHP would appreciate for some one pointing me to good solution.

parent page.php

```
display_cell6.appendChild(edit).innerHTML='<img id="edit" alt="Edit" class="'+obj[idx].id+'" onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:\'ajaxEditUserDetail.php\',boxid:\'frameless\',width:400,height:280,openjs:function(){openJS(this.id)}}); title="Edit" src="images/edit.png"></img>';


   function openJS(id){
        var id=parent.document.getElementById(id);
        alert(id);
   
    }
```

edit.php

```
    <div id="banner">
<span>Edit Customer Information</span>
</div>
<div id="form_container">
                                                     
<fieldset>
<div class="box-form">
    <form action="send.php" method="POST" id="userDetail" >
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label for="name_Req">Name <strong>*</strong></label>
                <input type="text" id="name_Req" name="name" value="test"       
title="Required! Please enter your name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="contact_Req_Email">E-mail <strong>*</strong></label>
                <input type="text" id="contact_Req_Email" name="email"    
title="Required! Please enter a valid email address" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="telephone_Tel">Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" id="telephone_Tel" name="telephone" 
title="Please     enter a valid telephone number" />
            </div>              
            <div>
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address" title="Please enter a 
valid address" />
            </div>                              
            <div>

                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="sub" class="button"  />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    
</div>

 </fieldset>
</div>
```